# ggplot2: bar plot order within group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have sample data I would like to make bar plot. Data are to be shown group within group.

sample data frame is as:

```r
sample<-data.frame("Flag"=c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),
        "type"=c("Best","Normal","Dormant","Lost","Cheap","Normal"), 
        "n" =c(9859,5008,3807,1747,1085,992))
```

I would like make bar plot within `Flag` ordered by `N` for the `type` column.

Here is making plot:

```
make_plot <-ggplot2::ggplot( sample, aes(fill=reorder(type,n), x=Flag, y=n)) +  
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") 

make_plot
```

I do not understand how to use reorder with factor. or factor with reorder

```r
sample$type <-factor(sample$type, 
   levels=c("Best","Normal","Dormant","Lost","Cheap","Normal"))
```

It gives error as there are duplicates in levels.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: @RonakShah -It was really close. Somehow the y-axis text was labels than count/numbers. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fct_inorder` from `forcats` package is what you need:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
ggplot(sample, aes(fill = fct_inorder(type), x=Flag, y=n)) +  
        geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]